# wifi: Scheme.for_cell fails with TypeError

Tags: python, wifi

Using the `wifi` package, here is what I did:

```
>>> cell = Cell.all('wlan0')[0]
>>> print cell
>>> scheme = Scheme.for_cell('wlan0', 'home', cell)
```

When I print cell it prints the ssid. When I run `scheme = Scheme.for_cell('wlan0', 'home', cell)`. It gives the error

```
>>> scheme = Scheme.for_cell('wlan0', 'home', cell)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/aaeronn/virt_proj/wifi_hack/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wifi/scheme.py", line 110, in for_cell
    return cls(interface, name, configuration(cell, passkey))
  File "/home/aaeronn/virt_proj/wifi_hack/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wifi/scheme.py", line 23, in configuration
    if len(passkey) != 64:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Whats wrong ? Where should I enter the password for that ssid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for `wifi.Scheme.for_cell`](https://wifi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scanning.html?highlight=for_cell#wifi.Scheme.for_cell) says it takes a `passkey` argument:

> *classmethod* **`for_cell`**(interface, name, cell, passkey=None)

So with some `passkey`, you would call

```
scheme = Scheme.for_cell('wlan0', 'home', cell, passkey)
```

Looking at the [source code for that package](https://github.com/rockymeza/wifi/blob/master/wifi/scheme.py), the `TypeError` raised there is a bug, or at least a sign of hasty design.

Comment: thanks for your reply and one more thing I want to know is that if I dont remember my passkey but I know the pin of my router then can I access my router and can be connected without knowing the password and just by knowing router pin